# Jquery Grid Checkbox value

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all I have grid with a checkbox column and made disabled. and a column with image button, when I click the image button, the corresponding check value of the checkbox in the row should be fetched.

This is my grid,

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Deleted") %>'  Text="InActive" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="images/Edit.gif"
                            OnClick='<%# Eval("ID", "ShowEditBox({0});return false;") %>' runat="server"
                            ToolTip="Edit" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="images/Delete.gif"
                            OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ID", "DeleteRecord({0});return false;") %>' runat="server"
                            ToolTip="Active/InActive" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Below is the Jquery method,

```
function ShowEditBox(id) 
{
    $("#divEditBox").slideDown("medium");
    var pid = 'PName' + id;
    var colIndex = 0;

    var $tr = $("#" + pid).parent().parent();
    $tr.find('td').each(function() {
        if (colIndex == 1) {
            $("#txtGroupName").val($(this).text());
        }
        if (colIndex == 2) {

            if (this.checked) { alert("true"); } else { alert("false"); } 

//            
//            alert($('#' + '<%= chkStatus.ClientID %>').is(':checked'));
//            alert($(this).text());
        }
        colIndex++;
    })
    $("#editId").val(id);
    $("#lblPopTitle").text("Modify Group");
}
```

when i click the edit button the showedit() jquery method always return the checkbox value as false.

anybody please help me on this....
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this` keyword in `this.checked`is the `td` in your `.each` function.
You first have to find the checkbox. Do something like :

```
var checked = $(this).find(input:checkbox).is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Your loop of TD should be like this, i have not checked it but it should be like this

```
$tr.find('td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).index == 1) {
            $("#txtGroupName").val($(this).text());
        }
        if ($(this).index == 2) {
            if($(this).find("input:checkbox").is(':checked'))
            {
                alert("true")
            }
        }
    })
```